# JPA 2.0 Criteria Builder using Fetch in where clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can i join fetch an Entity and use it in the where clause.

```
 Fetch<Transaction,Customer> customer =transaction.fetch(Transaction_.customer,JoinType.LEFT);
 cq.where(cb.equal(customer.get(Customer_.name), "xxx"));
```

I get the following error:
The method get(SingularAttribute) is undefined for the type Fetch

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511368/jpa-2-criteria-fetch-path-navigation

Comment: Thanks for the head's up. I saw that thread, i was hoping there would be a cleaner/better way then casting the fetch to a join.