# Hibernate Join two unrelated table when both has Composite Primary Key

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing java application using `hibernate 5.2` but without `HQL`

there is two table, `Transactions` and `ResponseCode`

[image]

The logic of select statement which I want to be generated by Hibernate should look like this select bellow

```
SELECT t.tranType
      ,t.tranId
      ,t.requestDate
      ,t.rcCode
      ,t.tranAmount
      ,r.description
      ,r.status
  FROM transactions t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN responseCode r
    ON t.rcCode = r.rcCode
   AND (r.lang = 'en')
 WHERE (t.merchant_id =5 )
```

But something is wrong in my code, here is my implementation snippet

**Transaction Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name = "merchant_id", nullable = true)
        private String merchantID;

        @Column(name = "tran_amount", nullable = true)
        private String tranAmount;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tran_type", nullable = true)
        private String tranType;

        @Column(name = "auth_request_date", nullable = true)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date authRequestDate;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tran_id", nullable = true)
        private String tranID;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="rc")
        private ResponseCode rc;

        // Contructos and getters/setters
```

**ResponseCode Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "response_codes")

public class ResponseCode implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "response_code")
    private String rcCode;

    @Column(name = "rc_status")
    private String rcStatus;

    @Column(name = "rc_description")
    private String rcDesc;

    @Column(name = "rc_lang")
    private String rcLang;
    // Contructos and getters/setters
```

**Implementation code**

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Transaction> criteria = builder.createQuery(Transaction.class);
Root<Transaction> transaction = criteria.from(Transaction.class);
Join<Transaction, ResponseCode> bJoin = transaction.join("rc",JoinType.LEFT);
bJoin.on(builder.equal(bJoin.get("rcLang"), tRequest.getLang()));

Predicate predicate = builder.and(transaction.get("merchantID").in(tRequest.getMerchantList()));
predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.between(transaction.get("authRequestDate"), dateFrom, dateTo));
criteria.where(predicate);
```

Hibernate Generates two select statement, first statement gets transactions list, and  second statement gets the response code details which is included in transactions list.

> **example:** *if there is 30000 transaction, and 15000 transaction has 000 response code, 5000 transaction has 116 response code and 10000 transaction has  400 response code, it will run second select statement
>   three times, for 000,116 and 400 rcCode.*

but the problem is that `ResponseCode` table contains several language for one response code
[image]

first select statement contains the restriction on language but second select statement does not has this restriction, and it does not meter which language is provided in first statement, the final result of transactions object contains for some transactions `en` language rc description and for some transactions `ge` language rc descriptions.

> *I think it depends on which language description was selected by oracle at last*

**Hibernate generated select I**

```
SELECT t.tran_type
      ,t.tran_id
      ,t.auth_request_date
      ,t.merchant_id
      ,t.rc
      ,t.tran_amount
  FROM transactions t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN response_codes r
    ON t.rc = r.response_code
   AND (r.rc_lang = ?)
 WHERE (t.merchant_id IN (?))
   AND (t.AUTH_REQUEST_DATE BETWEEN ? AND ?)
 ORDER BY t.AUTH_REQUEST_DATE ASC
```

**Hibernate generated select II**

```
SELECT r.response_code  
      ,r.rc_description 
      ,r.rc_lang        
      ,r.rc_status      
  FROM response_codes r
 WHERE r.response_code = ? 
 //this select statement should have 'AND r.rc_lang = ?'
```

> **P.s** *If I make `OneToMany` relation it gets 30000 transaction and
>   performs 30000 additional query to get response Code description for each
>   operation, known as N + 1 problem*

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: There is no bug here. A where clause doesn't change what an entity contains. It changes which entities are retrieved by the query. So if your where clause allows selecting a transaction t, when you ask for t's response code, you'll always get t's response code. Moreover, if there are several rows with the same response code, then the response code clearly can't be the ID of the entity: an ID is supposed to uniquely identify an entity, just as a primary key.

Comment: @JB Nizet I have edited question, please check if you have any Idea how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that

> Criteria API does not support joining unrelated entities. JPQL does
>   not support that either. However, Hibernate supports it in HQL since
>   5.1.  https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/join-two-table-when-both-has-composite-primary-key/1966

Maybe there is some workarounds, but in this case, I think the better way is to use HQL instead of Criteria API.

Here is HQL implementation code snippet (nothing was changed in entity classes)

```
String hql = "FROM Transaction t \r\n" + 
             " LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH t.rc r \r\n" +
             " WHERE (t.merchantID IN (:merchant_id))\r\n" +
             " AND (t.authRequestDate BETWEEN :from AND :to)\r\n" +
             " AND (r.rcLang = :rcLang or r.rcLang is null)\r\n";

Query query =  session.createQuery(hql,Transaction.class);
query.setParameter("merchant_id", tRequest.getMerchantList());
query.setParameter("rcLang", tRequest.getLang());
query.setParameter("from", dateFrom);
query.setParameter("to", dateTo);

List<Transaction> dbTransaction = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: You could also try `LEFT OUTER JOIN t.rc r WITH r.rcLang = :rcLang ...` which would include the extra condition directly into the join clause of the resulting SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Change the relation from `@OneToOne` to  `@OneToMany` and use `fetch` instead of `join`  , it will execute only one query and hopefully it works.

```
 Join<Transaction, ResponseCode> join =
        (Join<Transaction,ResponseCode>)transaction.fetch("rc",JoinType.LEFT);
```

and you can try it with `@OneToOne` too.

Comment: Cannot cast from Fetch<Object,Object> to Join<Transaction,ResponseCode>

Comment: @Jibo you tried with exact statement which is given above?

Comment: @Jibo its strange. I am actually using this and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jibo see this my question. may be it helps. some one tell the solution and that was work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061564/jpa-criteria-query-how-to-implement-join-on-two-tables-to-get-desired-result-i

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mapping. `rcCode` cannot be an identifier because it does not identify records uniquely. I think that it will bring a lot of problems. `ResponseCode` must have a different identifier.

`@OneToOne` means one to one. You have one transaction, one response code but many languages.

You can mapping (`@OneToOne`) a connection between a `Transaction` and a `ResponseCode` *with a specific language* (through a [composite key](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite)).

You can use `@OneToMany`, but usually in that case the reference should be from the `ResponseCode` table to the `Transaction` table.

But maybe you need 3 tables: transactions, response codes (with the code itself and its general information), response codes localizations (with messages on different languages). transactions one-to-one response_codes, response_codes one-to-many rc_localizations.

Or maybe you do not need hibernate-relation between `Transaction` and `ResponseCode`.

```
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable {
...
    @Column(name="rc")
    private String rc;
...
}
```

You can select the necessary `ResponseCode` by code and language. Two selects: 1 - select `Transaction` (with String rc-code); 2 - select `ResponseCode` (with the necessary language) by rc-code from `Transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping of both entities is wrong.

Let's start with the `ResponseCode` entity. Your table model shows a composite primary key that consists of the `RcCode` and `Lang` columns. But your entity mapping only declares the `rcCode` attribute as the primary key. You need to add an additional `@Id` annotation to the `rcLang` attribute of the `ResponseCode` entity.

This should be the fixed mapping of the `ResponseCode` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "response_codes")
public class ResponseCode implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "response_code")
    private String rcCode;

    @Column(name = "rc_status")
    private String rcStatus;

    @Column(name = "rc_description")
    private String rcDesc;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rc_lang")
    private String rcLang;

    // Contructors and getters/setters
}
```

After fixing the primary key of your `ReponseCode` entity, you need to reference both attributes/columns in the association mapping of your `Transaction` entity. With Hibernate 5.2, you can do that with 2 of Hibernate's `@JoinColumn` annotations. Older Hibernate versions and the JPA standard in version 2.1 need to wrap these annotations in an additional `@JoinColumns` annotation.

Here is the fixed mapping of your `Transaction` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "merchant_id", nullable = true)
    private String merchantID;

    @Column(name = "tran_amount", nullable = true)
    private String tranAmount;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tran_type", nullable = true)
    private String tranType;

    @Column(name = "auth_request_date", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date authRequestDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tran_id", nullable = true)
    private String tranID;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="rc_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JoinColumn(name="rc_lang", referencedColumnName = "lang")
    private ResponseCode rc;

    // Contructos and getters/setters
```

Comment: you can not add two '@JoinColumn' anotation without including it in to '@JoinColumns' anotation. There is no "rc_lang" column in 'Transactions' entity so it could not refer to 'rc_lang' column into reference entity.

Comment: You need to use Hibernate's `@JoinColumn` annotation. The one defined by the JPA 2.1 standard is not `@Repeatable` and therefore requires the `@JoinColumns` wrapper.

If there is no rc_lang column, than you need to use a @OneToMany association instead of the @OneToOne. Based on your table model, there might be multiple records in the `ResonseCode` table with the same id

Comment: @ThorbenJanssen In the question it's mentioned that, "P.s If I make OneToMany relation it gets 30000 transaction and performs 30000 additional query to get response Code description for each operation"

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped a single `ResponseCode` entity in `Transaction`, which is wrong. The response code is **not** a PK, it does not uniquely identifies a ResponseCode entity for a given Transaction entity. E.g. for a transaction with response code `000` there are 2 ResponseCode entities (with 'en' and 'ge' langs).

I recommend you to try to map a collection instead.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="rc")
private List<ResponseCode> rcList;
```

Since your query WHERE conditions apply to the Transaction only, you can simply query the Transaction entities. Hibernate cache will optimize the eventual subqueries you need for each response code (one query for '000', one for '116', etc).