# How to join two table when both has Composite Primary Key

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

There is two table `Transactions` and `ResponseCode`

[image]

I want to write hibernate 5.2 code without using `HQL` so that it generate this kind of select bellow

```
SELECT t.tranType
      ,t.tranId
      ,t.requestDate
      ,t.rcCode
      ,t.tranAmount
      ,r.description
      ,r.status
  FROM transactions t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN responseCode r
    ON t.rcCode = r.rcCode
   AND (r.lang = 'en')
 WHERE (t.merchant_id =5 )
```

Please, let me know how to join this two table using hibernate annotations in table `@Entities` so, that `transactions` table one record join to `ResponseCode` table one record

Comment: are you using repository ? I mean to say JPA or CRUD

Comment: Have you tried writing the HQL query yet?

Comment: @Navin Gelot I'm using Hibernate JPA (no spring, or other framework)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen No, I did not tried to write HQL

Comment: It would have helped your question if you at least posted a skeleton of a possible HQL query.  Otherwise, you are just asking us to write it for you from scratch.  Nothing wrong with that, but it increases the chances that you won't get an answer.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen here is the additional explanation of my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916500/hibernate-5-2-join-table-restriction-problem

Comment: Why have you asked a new, duplicate, question instead of improving your first one?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I have improved first one, do you have any Idea how to fix it?